# How to write php code inside jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I tried all possible ways to write php code inside a jquery code. Here is my code snippet:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.add_more', function(){
     var plugin_dir = "<?php plugins_url(); ?>";
     console.log(plugin_dir);
 });
```

Even I tried as follows:

```
$('body').on('click', '.add_more', function(){
    var plugin_dir = <?php plugins_url(); ?>;
    console.log(plugin_dir);
});
```

I am writing this code inside a wordpress plugin php file. I apologize if this question is duplicate. It kills my day. Any idea?

Comment: Your first attempt should be working. Make sure plugins_url() actually writes something and doesn't just returns the value. Try replacing plugins_url() with echo 'hello' and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I changed accordingly and now I can see <?php echo 'hello'; ?> in my console log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning value that way you can use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) or [`wp_add_inline_script()`](http://wp_add_inline_script) and create a plugin configuration JS object to use that everywhere.

**`PHP file`**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'script-handle',
        'your-script-uri/script.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        'version',
        true
    );

    wp_localize_script( 
        'script-handle',
        'pluginNameSpace',
        array(
            'url' => plugins_url()
        )   
    );
} );
```

**`JS file`**

```
$('body').on('click', '.add_more', function(){
    console.log( pluginNameSpace.url );
});
```

Comment: Would you say in more detail please. It seems to me it  will be good practice you are mentioning.

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan please check added an example. You'll get more details if you check those function doc. And yes it's best practice.

Comment: Agreed this is the best method rather than using the hack in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to echo the plugins_url()

```
$('body').on('click', '.add_more', function(){
     var plugin_dir = "<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>";
     console.log(plugin_dir);
 });
```

Comment: Now I can see <?php echo plugins_url(); ?> in console log